# Blender updating with addons (3rd party) without build in addons

Tags: add-on

When upgrading Blender, we can upgrade the settings and plugins of the previous version both from within the program and by moving the scripts\addons folder (including the config file), but the default plugins that come with blender in scripts\addons are switched to the new version with their old versions. I want to migrate from version 3.1 to version 3.5 with 3rd party plugins I have, but I don't want native old plugins from 3.1 to be migrated during this transfer. How can I solve this and why blender doesn't use a different file system for external plugins?

Comment: Hello. Unless I'm mistaken they don't, "native" addons are re-shipped with every new blender version, and overwritten when you install a new one. Would you mind sharing a screenshot of the culprit files ?